# Parameters Variation not running model in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

When I create a ParametersVariation simulation, the main model does not run. All I see is the default UI with iterations completed and replication. My end goal (as with most people) is to have a model go through a certain number of replications, but nothing is even running. There is limited documentation available on this. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how Parameters Variation is intended to work. If you're running 1000 runs and multiple replications with parallel runs, how can you see what's happening in Main in each?

Typically, the best way to benefit from such an experiment is to track the results of each run using elements from the ***Analysis*** palette or even better to export results to Excel or similar.

To be able to collect data, you need to write your code in ***Java actions*** fields with `root.` to access elements in main (or top-level agent).

Check the example below, where after each run a variable from main is added to a dataset in the Parameters Variation experiment. At the end of 100 runs for example, the dataset will have 100 values of the main variable, with 1 value for each run.

[image]

Comment: Thank you makes sense to me. My next question will be how to export data to excel but specifically the data rom the statistics_log. I will make a new question.